# JQuery remove focus from textbox

Tags: jquery

How do I remove the focus of a TextBox in JQuery?

**Edit:** This is the solution I was looking for:

```
$(this).trigger('blur');
```

For an unknown reason, `$(this).blur();` did not work. I created a new, clear solution and then it worked.

Comment: What's the point of this? If you blur the field when it's clicked on it can never be edited. You might as well just use `readonly`.

Comment: This really really sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I simplified my question to leave out irrelevant stuff. Naturally, I won't clear the textbox and then just remove the focus, but I wanted to know how to remove the focus programmatically.

Comment: @Kohnarik But there are many dupes regarding this already. `I've seen the .blur()` So you should have just tested it. And `$(this).trigger('blur');` is the same as `$(this).blur();`, so really doesn't make sense

Comment: Your edit makes no sense - `$obj.blur()` and `$obj.trigger('blur')` are *exactly* the same under the hood.

Comment: @A.Wolff I have rephrased my question. I have tested .blur() and this function does not do what I want. I have the solution now and I added it to my question.

Comment: @Kohnarik `I have tested .blur() and this function does not do what I want` That's not possible then...  Just provide MCVE and i will upvote this question BUT i'm sure you couldn't replicate it. And btw here, you are just misleading any futur readers

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Well, I don't know much about JQuery but a simple test made it clear for me that blur() does nothing, while trigger('blur') worked.

Comment: It really should do, but we're unable to help you effectively as you're spoon-feeding very little information.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry for that. In the end, I received a functioning solution. Thank you for trying to help me, though.

Comment: @A.Wolff I edited my question once more. I can't replicate the error, but after creating a new solution and using it there, it does indeed work.

Comment: @Kohnarik Maybe you had a browser cache issue or maybe you weren't actually using `$(this).blur()` but passing anything to it making it not trigger the blur behaviour, e.g this would failed: `$(this).blur({});`. Oh and anyway, what you really want is `this.blur();`

Comment: @A.Wolff I rebuilt my solution and blur() works in my main project now as well. Thank you for your patience & help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/eg64LxrL/)

```js
$(function () {
    $('input[type=text]').focus(function () {
        $(this).val('');
        // add the below line to trigger the blur event
        $(this).trigger('blur'); 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="abcdef">
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: you're welcome @Kohnarik

Answer (score 3):

you can force it to blur using trigger function

```
$("...").trigger("blur");
```

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).blur();` will do the trick. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxftfe8w/)

Answer (score 2):

Use .[blur().](http://api.jquery.com/blur/#fn)

**Bind an event handler to the "blur" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.**

```
$(this).trigger('blur');
```

Comment: yes, you should use $(this).trigger('blur');

Comment: What's the difference between these two?